# Extracting the values from nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, matrix

```
d= {0: {'Name': 'MN', 'volt': 1.0, 'an': 0.0}, 
    1: {'Name': 'LT', 'volt': 1.0, 'an': 5.8},
    2: {'Name': 'CK', 'volt': 1.0, 'an': 2.72}, 
    3: {'Name': 'QL', 'volt': 1.0, 'an': 0.33}}
```

I am trying to create a matrix from the above nested dictionary that would result in the following output:

```
[MN 1.0 0.0
 LT 1.0 5.8
 CK 1.0 2.72
 QL 1.0 0.33]
```

Using .values() function in python would result in the key names as well.

Comment: It is not possible by itself I thinK. You can not mix integer and strings like that. At least here, you have one list of one element. So please correct.

Comment: Try: `[list(x.values()) for x in d.values()]`

Comment: There is no built-in data structure as  _matrix_ in Python. You should probably clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can them in a list like this

```
>>> d = {0: {'Name': 'MN', 'volt': 1.0, 'an': 0.0}, 
         1: {'Name': 'LT', 'volt': 1.0, 'an': 5.8},
         2: {'Name': 'CK', 'volt': 1.0, 'an': 2.72}, 
         3: {'Name': 'QL', 'volt': 1.0, 'an': 0.33}}
>>> [list(i.values()) for i in d.values()]
[['MN', 1.0, 0.0],
 ['LT', 1.0, 5.8],
 ['CK', 1.0, 2.72],
 ['QL', 1.0, 0.33]]
```

You iterate over the values of the outer dictionary and then again, extract the values of interior dictionaries via `i.values` during iteration, store them in a list with list-comprehension.

If you want them flattened in a list

```
>>> sum([list(i.values()) for i in d.values()], [])
['MN', 1.0, 0.0, 'LT', 1.0, 5.8, 'CK', 1.0, 2.72, 'QL', 1.0, 0.33]
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!!